# Was there any influence/inspiration of “Mortal Engines Quartet” series by Philip Reeve on “Carnival Row”?

Tags: influences, mortal-engines, carnival-row

Carnival Row's premise is a [mish-mash of influences and inspirations](https://thespinoff.co.nz/tv/30-08-2019/review-carnival-row-is-stuck-in-the-mud-of-the-fantasy-ghetto/), from Neil Gaiman to Mortal Engines.

Is there any evidence the Mortal Engines Quartet influenced and/or inspired the show's elements?